# Resize window and content continuously

Tags: 11.04, compiz, window-management

Is it possible to get Ubuntu to continuously resize a window and it's content? Looking in the `CompizConfig Settings Manager` under re-size window it has the options: Normal, Outline, Rectangle, Stretch neither of which do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal does this.

It's ridiculously CPU-intensive though, which is why it defaults to rectangle.

Comment: Oh, the lag had me thinking it didn't show anything until you let go. I guess I'll have to test my fluid layouts in a virtual machine.. :)

Answer (score 10):

I know you (Kit Sunde) don't need all this, but for everyone else..

This assumes you have CompizConfig Setting Manager (compizconfig-settings-manager) installed.

1. Go to **System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager** if running classic Gnome, or search for **CompizConfig Settings Manager** in the Dash if running Unity.
2. Find the **Resize Window** plugin; it's under **Window Management**. Open it and go to the **General** tab. The top setting is **Default Resize Mode**.

   - **Normal** resizes the windows content on-the-fly.
   - **Outline** doesn't change the window until you release it. It shows an empty rectangle to indicate the size the window will be.
   - **Rectangle** is the same as **Outline**, except the rectangle is filled in.
   - **Stretch** doesn't resize the window on-the-fly, but instead stretches the window content as if you were stretching a video.

In all cases, the window content should continue to change as appropriate, e.g. a video will continue playing.

Answer (score 1):

Normal resize doesn't work well in Ubuntu Classic. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/803296